# How to update sqlite on iPhone app

Tags: iphone, sqlite

I have an iPhone application that uses a sqlite3 database for saving data and before I release the app I need to be sure that some of the tables data (that the user has saved) must be copied to the new database.

How should I manage this migration. I was thinking about separating the database and the queries. Is that bad? So when the app opens I check if the database is in the document folder, if not copy the database and run the queries in the separate file. Then when it is a new version I check the version number and run just the queries in the file (which update the data and alter some of them), and not copy the database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way of doing this is to have a table in your database that contains a schema version of the database.

Once a user have a database in the documents folder (which was probably copied from a premade database from the app bundle) you should make changes to that database to keep it in sync with the current schema. This includes upgrading the schema and any changed data.

You can do this by bundling a number of sql scripts in your app that will bring the users database schema forward one step at a time, e.g.:

1. Read schema version from users database => 3 (current is 5)
2. Execute sql script "schema_3_to_4.sql"
3. Execute sql script "schema_4_to_5.sql"
4. All done - ready to use

If you don't have a schema version in your current db, just regard this as version 0 and add the table in your version 1 update, e.g:

```
begin exclusive transaction;

create table schema (version integer);
insert into schema(version) values (1);

create table temp_update as select * from question;
drop table question;
create table question(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, new_answer INTEGER);
insert into question(id, new_answer) select id, 42 from temp_update;
drop table temp_update;

commit;
```

Comment: Thank you! So what you are basically saying is that the first time the user download the application, the database will be copied from the bundle to the document folder. When the user updates the application I update the database by loading sql-queries which alter the database from a file?

Comment: Thank you, however what do you think about this approach? It can't be that dumb when not using Core Data? I have not time to understand how to model this in Core Data and it is a bit fun to actually make it myself too, thats the reason.

Comment: @Andreas I certainly do not think this approach is dumb - I use it myself for simple databases :-) I have also seen it used a couple of other places where sqlite is accessed directly.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the best approach is migrating from a manual handling of the sqlite3 database to a Core-Data-based one. [Core Data](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreData/cdProgrammingGuide.html) provides you with a lot of tools for defining and modelling data, including a super easy (when available) [lightweight migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008426-SW1) process that will incredibly ease the data migration process between various data base versions.

Using a [lightweight migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmLightweight.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40008426-SW1) (or the more complex [custom manual migration](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/CoreDataVersioning/Articles/vmMigrationProcess.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40005508-SW1)) your problems will be automatically solved.